# How to pass headers in axios as secret-key

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am using jsonbin.io and hosted a json data as private bin.
I am calling a axios get request to fetch that data. I have to pass my secret-key in headers as

headers{
secret-key: mysecretkey
}

but axios does not allow key in header as secret-key

```
const secretKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY;
const localUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_URL;

const fetchPhotosFlocal = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(localUrl, {
     headers: {
        secret-key: secretKey,
     },
  });
  console.log(response);   };
```

**secret-key gives error at compile time and "secret-key" can not fetch data what should i do now ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved i checked their documentation they are passing secret_key in string code.**

```
req.setRequestHeader("secret-key", "<SECRET_KEY>");
```

This runs fine

```
const secretKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY;
const localUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_URL;
const fetchPhotosFlocal = async () => {

const response = await axios.get(localUrl, { 
headers: {
    "secret-key": secretKey,
 },
  });
  console.log(response); };
```

Answer (score 2):

`secret-key` is not a valid identifier in JavaScript, as they cannot contain hyphens (see the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) for more details.

In your case, you can simply put the name of your header in quotes, like this:

```js
const secretKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY;
const localUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_URL;

const fetchPhotosFlocal = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(localUrl, {
     headers: {
        "secret-key": secretKey,
     },
  });
  console.log(response);   
};
```

Comment: No its not working still i'm not able to fetch data. I checked the url and secret-key both in postman its working that means server is responding. but secret-key is not varified.

Comment: Problem solved i checked their documentation they are passing secret_key in string code req.setRequestHeader("secret-key", "<SECRET_KEY>");

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
const fetchPhotosFlocal = async () => axios.get(localUrl, {
     headers: {
        'secret-key': secretKey,
     },
  });

const resp = await fetchPhotosFlocal();
console.log(resp);
```

Comment: no its not working still i'm not able to fetch data. I checked the url and secret-key both in postman its working that means server is responding. but secret-key is not varified

Comment: @ShashankDubey please check header on server side if it has `{ "secret-key" :  ".... " }` or not. it should be in `req.headers` if it is nodejs server.

Comment: Problem solved i checked their documentation they are passing secret_key in string code req.setRequestHeader("secret-key", "<SECRET_KEY>");

Answer (score 0):

You can set a secret key globally.

```
export const baseAxios = axios.create({

  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',

  headers: {
    'secret-key': 'secretKey',
  },

});
```

Then call >

```
 const fetchPhotosFlocal = async () => baseAxios.get(localUrl);
    
    const resp = await fetchPhotosFlocal();
    console.log(resp);
```